# jquery, javascript not working in bootstrap

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, twitter-bootstrap

I'm using JQuery and bootstrap, and when I try to click the button that should invoke the function, it doesn't work. I've looked in the developer console and there is nothing there, anyone know?

```
<html>
    <head>
        <title>Bill</title>

        <link rel="stylesheet" href="css/bootstrap.min.css"/>
        <link rel="stylesheet" href="css/jumbotron-narrow-me.css"/>
        <script src="js/jquery-2.1.3.min.js"/>
        <script src="js/bootstrap.min.js"/>

        <script type="text/javascript">
        var count=0;

        $('#ocs').click(function(){
            count++;
            $('#cookies').html('0Cs : ' + count);
        });
        </script>
    </head>

    <body>
        <div class="jumbotron">
            <p class="lead"> 
                welcome to opposition clicker, its amazing. it has one upgrade.
                "opposition" when you get this, you will get +100 0Cs' every second.
            </p>
            <br><br/>
        </div>
        <div class="container" id="cookies">aasasa</div> 
        <button id="ocs" type="button" class="btn btn-lg btn-success">0Cs'</button>
    </body>
</html>
```

Comment: Check your log. Any errors?

Comment: Best to close your `<script>` tags with `</script>`..Sure jQuery is loaded?

Comment: Sandeep, I just did that.. And got an error : Uncaught SyntaxError: Unexpected token ;

Comment: Do this...bind your click event using `.on`.. like this `$('#ocs').on('click', function(){...your code goes here...});`

Comment: Done that, same error :/

Comment: Check my answer working plunker :-)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You just need to close some script tags properly and place your script
in the bottom:-)

```
<html>

  <head>
    <title>Bill</title>
    <script data-require="jquery@*" data-semver="2.1.3" src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-2.1.3.min.js"></script>
    <link data-require="bootstrap@*" data-semver="3.3.1" rel="stylesheet" href="//maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.1/css/bootstrap.min.css" />
    <script data-require="bootstrap@*" data-semver="3.3.1" src="//maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.1/js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>
  </head>

  <body>
    <div class="jumbotron">
      <p class="lead"> 
                welcome to opposition clicker, its amazing. it has one upgrade.
                "opposition" when you get this, you will get +100 0Cs' every second.
            </p>
      <br />
      <br />
    </div>
    <div class="container" id="cookies">aasasa</div>
    <button id="ocs" type="button" class="btn btn-lg btn-success">0Cs'</button>
    <script type="text/javascript">
        var count=0;

        $('#ocs').click(function(){
            count++;
            $('#cookies').html('0Cs : ' + count);
        });
        </script>
  </body>

</html>
```

[Plunker](http://plnkr.co/edit/vEyPm9J3CTHut5pitYps?p=preview)

PS:- I didn't added the jumbotron-narrow-me.css in example because it is not available on plunker but hope it helps :-)

Comment: was it the script tags you changed?

Comment: yup just added latest scripts of each category and added your script just before  the end of body :-)

Comment: Happy coding dear :-)

Comment: wait, i just looked at the console, and i got this ;( file://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.1/js/bootstrap.min.js Failed to load resource: net::ERR_FILE_NOT_FOUND                                                                          
file://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.1/css/bootstrap.min.css Failed to load resource: net::ERR_FILE_NOT_FOUND
index.html:20 Uncaught SyntaxError: Unexpected token ;

Comment: in my answer i deleted that file please delete it from plunker as well Updated plunker http://plnkr.co/edit/pKaMpLNkGSLtAtvcNvvx?p=preview. I was using cdn for that :-)

Comment: do you know what to do?

Comment: Syntax error you didn't close close ")"  $(document).ready(function(){} Plunker:- http://plnkr.co/edit/DCQAQ5IyaH1SyC1qd5yf?p=preview

Answer (score 1):

Ensure that your click handler is declared **after the DOM is ready**

Like that :

```
$(document).ready(function(){
    $('#ocs').click(function(){
        // something
    });
});
```

Answer (score 1):

Today I have found the solution to this question. If anyone is struggling with same problem in 2022 then you just have to make use of script tags and Jquery tags as given below:

```
<link rel="stylesheet"
    href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.0.0/css/bootstrap.min.css">
<link rel="stylesheet"
    href="//code.jquery.com/ui/1.12.1/themes/base/jquery-ui.css">

<script src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-3.6.0.js" ></script>
<script src="https://code.jquery.com/ui/1.12.1/jquery-ui.js"></script>
```

Answer (score 0):

use the .text() function instead of the .html()

Comment: Yeah, I did that.. No effect :(

Comment: even if it doesn't fix the problem, its the correct function to use for putting text into an element.

Answer (score 0):

try this:

```
$(function(){
 $(document).on('click','#ocs',function(e){ // do somethign here
 });
});
```